# How can I understand index from cursor in a XY chart in Amcharts where bullets can be dragged?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, amcharts5

I am using an XY chart in Amcharts with series. In this graph, I use a pre-defined array and set its data like this:

```
series.data.setAll(example);
```

I am inspired by the idea behind [this v3 demo.](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/manipulate-chart-data-with-mouse/) I want to achieve a bullet's index by clicking on the bullet. Is there a way to achieve this information?